# SQL Server data to HTML layout

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hey all, I am trying this code below to be placed into my own HTML layout for export to a PDF.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT i.InvoiceNumber as 'Invoice', 
'$' + CONVERT(varchar(50),round((CONVERT(int,Points) * .1),0)) AS 'Amount', 
'$' + CONVERT(varchar(50), 1.50) AS 'Fee' 
FROM tblHGP HGP, OrderDetails OD, tblInvoices i
        JOIN tblCS cs ON i.InvoiceNumber = cs.InvoiceNumber
        JOIN tblEC ac ON i.InvoiceNumber = ac.InvoiceNumber 
WHERE cs.SoldTo = HGP.ECardInd 
AND issued BETWEEN '2010-09-01' AND '2010-09-30 23:59:59' 
AND CountryCode = 'US' 
AND HGP.invoiceNumber = OD.orderdetailsid 
Order by i.InvoiceNumber
```

Right now it returns 6 records and i need to be able to create a HTML for **EACH** record it finds (and in this example, 6)

This is some of my HTML code:

```
SET @theHTML= '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css"><!--
span.cls_002{font-family:Arial,serif;font-size:15.6px;color:rgb(0,0,0);font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}
div.cls_002{font-family:Arial,serif;font-size:13.6px;color:rgb(0,0,0);font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}
....
<div style="position:absolute; left:90.00px; top:313.08px; width: 249px" class="cls_004">' + @whatReportFees + '</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:347px; top:313.32px" class="cls_004">' + @FeesQty + '</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:424.44px; top:313.32px" class="cls_004">$1.50</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:482.89px; top:313.32px" class="cls_004">$' + convert(varchar(30), CONVERT(MONEY, @FeesTotal, 3), 3) + '</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:90px; top:329px; width: 249px" class="cls_004">' + @whatReportRed + '</div>
 etc...
```

I don't really know how to incorporate the HTML into the query so that it creates a new one every time it finds a new invoice number. The **whatReportRed**, **FeesQty** would be where the data would need to go.

Then I would run this to crate the PDF

```
 exec clrPdfFromHTML '\\reports\report.pdf', @theHTML
```

Any input would be great! :o)

**TESTING**

```
DECLARE @HtmlHead varchar(4000); SET @HtmlHead = '<html><head></head><body>'
DECLARE @HtmlTail varchar(4000); SET @HtmlTail = '</body></html>'

DECLARE @theHTML varchar(4000)
DECLARE CreatePdf_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT @HtmlHead
    + '<div>' + i.InvoiceNumber + '</div>'
    + @HtmlTail AS theHTML
FROM 
    (SELECT 
    DISTINCT i.InvoiceNumber as 'Invoice', 
    '$' + CONVERT(varchar(50),round((CONVERT(int,Points) * .1),0)) AS 'Amount', 
    '$' + CONVERT(varchar(50), 1.50) AS 'Fee' 
    FROM tblHGP HGP, OrderDetails OD, tblInvoices i
    JOIN tblCS cs ON i.InvoiceNumber = cs.InvoiceNumber
    JOIN tblEC ac ON i.InvoiceNumber = ac.InvoiceNumber 
     WHERE cs.SoldTo = HGP.ECardInd 
    AND issued BETWEEN '2010-09-01' AND '2010-09-30 23:59:59' 
    AND CountryCode = 'US' 
    AND HGP.invoiceNumber = OD.orderdetailsid)
OPEN CreatePdf_Cursor
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM CreatePdf_Cursor INTO @theHTML
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK
    --exec clrPdfFromHTML '\\reports\report.pdf', @theHTML
END
CLOSE CreatePdf_Cursor
DEALLOCATE CreatePdf_Cursor
```

ERROR

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
```

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPEN'.

David

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid doing this in Reporting Services?

Comment: its what the office "standard" is for doing reports. I cant do anything on my own since everyone knows only how to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you added under TESTING should read:

```
DECLARE @HtmlHead varchar(4000); SET @HtmlHead = '<html><head></head><body>'
DECLARE @HtmlTail varchar(4000); SET @HtmlTail = '</body></html>'

DECLARE @theHTML varchar(4000)
DECLARE CreatePdf_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT @HtmlHead
    + '<div>' + Cast(mySubquery.Invoice as varchar(100)) + '</div>'
    + @HtmlTail AS theHTML
FROM 
    (SELECT 
    DISTINCT i.InvoiceNumber as 'Invoice', 
    '$' + CONVERT(varchar(50),round((CONVERT(int,Points) * .1),0)) AS 'Amount', 
    '$' + CONVERT(varchar(50), 1.50) AS 'Fee' 
    FROM tblHGP HGP, OrderDetails OD, tblInvoices i
    JOIN tblCS cs ON i.InvoiceNumber = cs.InvoiceNumber
    JOIN tblEC ac ON i.InvoiceNumber = ac.InvoiceNumber 
     WHERE cs.SoldTo = HGP.ECardInd 
    AND issued BETWEEN '2010-09-01' AND '2010-09-30 23:59:59' 
    AND CountryCode = 'US' 
    AND HGP.invoiceNumber = OD.orderdetailsid) as mySubquery
OPEN CreatePdf_Cursor
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM CreatePdf_Cursor INTO @theHTML
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK
    --exec clrPdfFromHTML '\\reports\report.pdf', @theHTML
END
CLOSE CreatePdf_Cursor
DEALLOCATE CreatePdf_Cursor
```

Comment: Ok, i corrected that but i am getting the error **Msg 245, Level 16, state 1, Line 21 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '<html><head></head><body><div>' to data type int** on **OPEN CreatePdf_Cursor**

Comment: Ok I've cast the int to a varchar now. You should really be able to figure out all these little tweaks to the example for yourself. This is not the place to have someone do your work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, webturner. I'm new to MSSQL and learning by example as i go.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a stored procedure for each row in a result set really calls for a cursor, its one of the few things you can't do with set based SQL unless you can pull apart the stored procedure.

To use a simpler example:

```
DECLARE @HtmlHead varchar(4000); SET @HtmlHead = '<html><head></head><body>'
DECLARE @HtmlTail varchar(4000); SET @HtmlTail = '</body></html>'

DECLARE @theHTML varchar(4000)
DECLARE CreatePdf_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT @HtmlHead
        + '<div>' + col1 + '</div>'
        + @HtmlTail AS theHTML
    FROM table
OPEN CreatePdf_Cursor
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM CreatePdf_Cursor INTO @theHTML
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK

    exec clrPdfFromHTML '\\reports\report.pdf', @theHTML
END
CLOSE CreatePdf_Cursor
DEALLOCATE CreatePdf_Cursor
```

With cursors like this I prefer to break in the middle of an infinite loop rather than repeating the FETCH NEXT code.

Comment: Of course you need to make report.pdf dynamic, otherwise it will be overwritten each row.

Comment: Where would the basic query that i have in my OP be placed within your query above, @webturner?

Comment: Replace the SELECT statement between declaring the cursor and opening it. Remember it needs to return a single column which is the entire @theHTML value.

Comment: Has errors:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'. **DECLARE CreatePdf_Cursor CURSOR FOR**
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 16
Must declare the scalar variable "@theHTML". **FETCH NEXT FROM CreatePdf_Cursor INTO @theHTML**

Comment: Edited, I forgot the datatype for @theHTML

Comment: You need to give the subquery a name. i.e. line 20 ends "OD.orderdetailsid) AS I"